# how to add another view to my initial view on uitable view on footer?

Tags: swift, uitableview

]I recently added a label to a custom view on the method , but, haven't been able to add and append other views to my initial custom view on uitable view. Haven't been able to make the function return a tuple..., tried:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

  let label = UILabel()
  label.textColor = .darkGray
  label.textAlignment = .center
  label.text = "Zero Zilch Zippal"
  label.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Medium", size: 30)

  let label2 = UILabel()
  label2.textColor = .darkGray
  label2.textAlignment = .center
  label2.text = "But it doesn't need to be..."
  label2.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Medium", size: 38)
  label.addSubview(label2)
  label2.anchor(self.view.topAnchor, left: 

  self.view.leftAnchor, bottom: self.view.bottomAnchor, right: 
  self.view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 250, leftConstant: 0, 
 bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 
 0)
 // let view = [label, label2]
  return label
}
```

**Also tried to return a array, but neither has worked for me...**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: [Int]) -> UIView? {

   let label = UILabel()
   label.textColor = .darkGray
   label.textAlignment = .center
   label.text = "Zero Zilch Zippal"
   label.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Medium", size: 30)

   let label2 = UILabel()
   label2.textColor = .darkGray
   label2.textAlignment = .center
   label2.text = "But it doesn't need to be..."
   label2.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Medium", size: 38)
   label.addSubview(label2)
   label2.anchor(self.view.topAnchor, left: 
 self.view.leftAnchor, bottom: self.view.bottomAnchor, right: 
 self.view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 250, leftConstant: 0, 
 bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 
 0)
    let view = [label, label2]
    return view
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to do so like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let result = resultView

    // recreate insets from existing ones in the table view
    let width = tableView.bounds.width
    let sepFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: width, height: 1)

    // create layer with separator, setting color
    let sep = CALayer()
    sep.frame = sepFrame
    sep.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor?.cgColor
    result?.layer.addSublayer(sep)

    return result
}
```

Try starting with one view.